# Tkinter better backgrounds

Tags: python, tkinter, background, tkinter-canvas

[I have managed to create this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuQaV.png)

I am using an oval with a different shade to create this.

```
def Banner():
    canvas.create_oval(-300, 1600, 4000, 200, fill="gray38", outline="gray38", width=4)
    banner_label = Label (canvas, width=30, height=2, font=font3, text = "FITNESS FIRST", bg="gray30", fg = "white")
    canvas_banner_label = canvas.create_window(500, 200, window=banner_label)
```

However i was wondering if theres anyway i could get the oval to almost take priority, and overlap the Label so that the oval is in front of it, allowing the pattern to be visible all the way through

Comment: Unfortunately i dont understand OOP. I'm a beginner here, sorry. Any chance this could be translated into procedural? Also i was thinking maybe i could add a shape with lower opacity to make the darker grey look lighter? Is that possible?

Comment: Please reread the issue i have made some changes. Thanks!

Comment: Can you noot chose which one gets placed first? Like in word you chose which image gets 'brought to the front'

Comment: Also what if instead of a label i use an image, wuold that work? That way i could create an identical version of the label in photoshop and just use it as an image.

Comment: Oh I see your problem now. Sorry. I believe you can just write the text without a background. Let me look into it. Look into `create_text` for canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with using `Label()` on the canvas is the label itself has its own background and will always be at the same level as the text so you cannot overlap your canvas image behind the text. However canvas has a method called `create_text` that will draw the text directly on the canvas instead of using a label.

Here is an example using `create_text` for canvas.

In the `create_text` method the first 2 arguments are coordinates then all you need is the text font and fill is the color.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=800, height=650, bg="darkgrey")
canvas.create_oval(-300, 1600, 4000, 200, fill="gray38", outline="gray38", width=4)
canvas.create_text(400,325, text="FITNESS FIRST", font=("Purisa", 60),fill="white")

canvas.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: Love you so much <3

Comment: I don't work with canvas all that much so I didn't realize sooner what it is you were asking for. Sorry for all the confusion  :D